# ogr: how to use epsg database for RD New projection?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr

I'm trying to assign [this EPSG projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992/) to my newly created shapefiles using `ogr`.
The [OGR Projections Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/osr_tutorial.html) says:

> ...any geographic coordinate system in the EPSG database can be set by it's GCS code number if the EPSG database is available

But this doesn't work for me:

```
spatialReference = ogr.osr.SpatialReference()
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("Amersfoort / RD New")
```

returns `6` at the prompt.

Doesn't work either (also returns `6` at the prompt by the way):

```
spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(28992)
```

This does work (returns 0 at the prompt):

```
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
```

If I define the proj4-string manually it works too (also returns 0).

```
proj4_str = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889..."
spatialReference.ImportFromProj4(proj4_str)
```

**Conclusion**: Not all codes from the EPSG database are available. The `spatialReference.XXX()` -methods return a code for setting the projection successfully or not(?). Has somebody more experience concerning these techniques and can explain what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

EPSG:28992 is projected system, not geographical so you cannot call SetWellKnownGeogCS() for it. You need to define both ellipsoid (GeogCS) and projection method (ProjCS) for projected systems. For UTM projection you can set both explicitly:

```
proj = osr.SpatialReference()
proj.SetProjCS("UTM 30N (WGS84)")
proj.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
proj.SetUTM(30, True)
```

where SetProjCS() only sets name, not the parameters. For non-UTM projections calling

```
proj.ImportFromEPSG(28992)
```

sets both for you (ellipsoid and projection).

Comment: The GCS used for Amersfoort RD New is `EPSG:4289 Amersfoort`. Can you try if that wroks?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRSpatialReference.html#a096b8dde4fd2eb475acd376060940b02):

> The following well known text values are currently supported:
>
> - "WGS84": same as "EPSG:4326" but has no dependence on EPSG data files.
> - "WGS72": same as "EPSG:4322" but has no dependence on EPSG data files.
> - "NAD27": same as "EPSG:4267" but has no dependence on EPSG data files.
> - "NAD83": same as "EPSG:4269" but has no dependence on EPSG data files.
> - "EPSG:n": same as doing an ImportFromEPSG(n).

That explains why

```
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("Amersfoort / RD New")
```

doesn't work. The code below

```
spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(28992)
```

works for my machine while

```
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("EPSG:28992")
```

doesn't. Can you test it on your machine?

<strike>doesn't work,I think it's still not in the EPSG database that comes with GDAL. ( Got no results while grepping for 28992 in csv files that contain the EPSG codes )</strike>
I still don't know.

Comment: "EPSG:n": same as doing an ImportFromEPSG(n)." should do the trick for n = 28992, right? Or what am I missing? Which csv file do you mean? I couldn't find a list with the EPSG codes.

Comment: Odd. spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(28992) works for me while spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS("Amersfoort / RD New") doesn't. What is your OS btw? I'm on Windows and I found them on C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal

Comment: I'm on windows, too. Just checked if I could find the csv and the COORD_REF is 28992. So it should work after all.

Comment: Just tested it again. Still doesn't work. What is the csv file called on your machine?

Comment: It's a whole directory. Lots of csv files. Which one doesn't work? EPSG:7415? Have you tried spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(28992)? That one works, at least.

Comment: Well, the csv that contains the projections is called 'compdcs.csv', at least with my installation. I had tried `spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(28992)` before asking already, re-tried just now, failed again.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your version of GDAL? I'm using version 1.9

Comment: Yeah, me too. Strange. I have to go now. But thanks for helping me out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5921/discussion-between-r-k-and-larsvegas)